# React - Rendering an array of objects using Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

I'm trying to `render an array of objects using Map` and so far I've only been able to render the first item to the browser.

I figured something's up with my .map function, but I don't know enough about React and JS to pinpoint the problem.

Here's my App.js file:

// `import` stuff is here

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
    this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('THE-JSON-URL-IS-HERE')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({ items: data });
    });

 render() {

const { items } = this.state;

return (
  <div className="App">

    { items.map((item, num) => {
        return (
          <div className="people">

            <div className="elem">
              <p key={num}>{item.elems}</p>   
            </div>     

              <p key={num}><strong>{item.name}</strong></p>
              <p key={num}><small>{item.title}</small></p>             

            <div className="hidden">
              <p key={num}><small>{item.email}</small></p>
              <p key={num}><small><strong>Office: </strong>{item.office}</small></p>
            </div>
            {/* <p>{item.manager}</p> */}
          </div>

        );
    })}        
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here's a sample of the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "elems": "Pr",
    "name": "Abby Langdale",
    "title": "President",
    "email": "alangdale0@hubpages.com",
    "office": "Javanrud",
    "manager": [
      {
        "elems": "Vp",
        "name": "Johnnie Mouncey",
        "title": "Vice President",
        "email": "jmouncey0@cnet.com",
        "office": "Canto",
        "manager": [
          {
            "elems": "Vp",
            "name": "Concordia Burgwyn",
            "title": "VP Quality Control",
            "email": "cburgwyn0@dyndns.org",
            "office": "Zhoukou",
            "manager": [
              {
                "elems": "En",
                "name": "Prissie Sainsberry",
                "title": "Web Developer IV",
                "email": "psainsberry0@yellowbook.com",
                "office": "Tugu",
                "manager": null
              },
```

etc. Abby's info is all that I've rendered.

Comment: You have lots of nested arrays. You either need to recursively flatten this data or use recursive maps. Approach depends also on what output you are expecting with the nested items

Comment: If the json sample is your "array" data, you're not really looking at rendering an array, but a heirarchy / object graph, and you'd need to some recursion, not the map function, to render that.  If that's the case, I recommend revising your title & description for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're nesting arrays and objects into your first array element, the length of items is 1 and the only element is the Abby element with the rest of the data nested inside of it. To map through all of the elements, `items` should look like this array:

```
[
  {
    "elems": "Pr",
    "name": "Abby Langdale",
    "title": "President",
    "email": "alangdale0@hubpages.com",
    "office": "Javanrud",
    "manager": ""
  },
  {
    "elems": "Vp",
    "name": "Johnnie Mouncey",
    "title": "Vice President",
    "email": "jmouncey0@cnet.com",
    "office": "Canto",
    "manager": ""
  },
  {
    "elems": "Vp",
    "name": "Concordia Burgwyn",
    "title": "VP Quality Control",
    "email": "cburgwyn0@dyndns.org",
    "office": "Zhoukou",
    "manager": ""
  },
  {
    "elems": "En",
    "name": "Prissie Sainsberry",
    "title": "Web Developer IV",
    "email": "psainsberry0@yellowbook.com",
    "office": "Tugu",
    "manager": null
  }
]
```

If you need to maintain the relationship of managers, you can add an id to each object and reference it from another object.

```
  [
      {
        "elems": "Pr",
        "name": "Abby Langdale",
        "title": "President",
        "email": "alangdale0@hubpages.com",
        "office": "Javanrud",
        "manager": "",
        "id" : 1
      },
      {
        "elems": "Vp",
        "name": "Johnnie Mouncey",
        "title": "Vice President",
        "email": "jmouncey0@cnet.com",
        "office": "Canto",
        "manager": 1
      },
      ...
]
```

You would need a filter helper function to do the correct lookup for a manager's name but it should work.

Comment: Hey thanks! I flattened the array as per your Option 1 and rendered the data. If I had to maintain the relationship of the managers I would've gone with your Option 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try flattening the array first. You would need to know the maximum number of levels that the array will have. Once it's flattened, you can use your map function:

```
const flatItems = items.flat(3);    // flatten up to 3 levels
items.map((item, num) => {
        return ( <render your div> );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that the nested array was part of the problem. I flattened it and was able to render the data.